# Linq to XML -Dictionary conversion

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

*How to store the nodes of the following into Dictionary where int is an autogenerated Key and string (value of the node) using LINQ ?*

**`Elements:`**

```
XElement instructors =
         XElement.Parse(
                          @"<instructors>
                               <instructor>Daniel</instructor>
                               <instructor>Joel</instructor>
                               <instructor>Eric</instructor>
                               <instructor>Scott</instructor>
                               <instructor>Joehan</instructor> 
                         </instructors>"
        );
```

**`partially attempted code is given below :`**

```
var  qry = from instr in instructors.Elements("instructor")
where((p,index)=> **incomplete**).select..**incomplete**;
```

How to turn my selection into `Dictionary<int,String>` ? (Key should start from 1;In Linq  indicies start from Zero).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about:

```
var dictionary = instructors.Elements("instructor")
                            .Select((element, index) => new { element, index })
                            .ToDictionary(x => x.index + 1,
                                          x => x.element.Value);
```

Comment: Have you written any special articles on LINQ ?

Comment: Not really - I blog about it every so often though.