# How to scan XElement and put all the element ( with value ) in Dictionary?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

My input is XElement object - and i need to convert this object to Dictionary

The XElement is look like this

```
 <Root>
    <child1>1</child1>
    <child2>2</child2>
    <child3>3</child3>
    <child4>4</child4>
 </Root>
```

And the output that i actually need to return is

Dictionary that look like this

```
[ Child1, 1 ]
[ Child2, 2 ]
[ Child3, 3 ]
[ Child4, 4 ]
```

How can i do it ?

thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you try anything already? If yes, please post.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're looking for the `ToDictionary()` method:

```
root.Elements().ToDictionary(x => x.Name.LocalName, x => x.Value)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

Dictionary<string, int> result = doc.Root.Elements()
    .ToDictionary(k => k.Name.LocalName, v => int.Parse(v.Value));
```

Answer (score 2):

You're all missing the point.

The keys are meant to be "ChileX", as in the country. :)

```
var xml = XElement.Parse("<Root><child1>1</child1><child2>2</child2><child3>3</child3><child4>4</child4></Root>");
var d = xml.Descendants()
   .ToDictionary(e => "Chile" + e.Value, e => v.Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
XElement root = XElement.Load("your.xml");
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (XElement el in root.Elements())
    dict.Add(el.Name.LocalName, el.Value);
```

or

For **linq** solution check @jon skeet answer : [Linq to XML -Dictionary conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593235/linq-to-xml-dictionary-conversion)